# maven plugin parameter only available in execute

Tags: maven, parameter-passing, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm writing a maven plugin with parameters.

The parameters are correctly initiated

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo '...' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) includes = [subpackage]
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /Users/username/dev/project/output
[DEBUG]   (f) sources = [/Users/username/dev/project/src/main/java/io/packagea, /Users/username/dev/project/src/main/java/io/packageb]
```

The parameters are correctly initiated in method `execute`, but are then `null` in called methods : raises NullPointerException. If I pass the parameter of the mojo as parameters to called methodes, then

Here an example parameter :

```
@Parameter
private String[] includes;
```

I do not identify why.

The full code is on my github repo (on feature branch) : [*branch deleted as answer is clear on the origin of the issue*]

plugin can be called with `mvn livingdoc:wordcloud` on a project.

The plugin browse code for @Wordcloud annotations but no need to reproduce issue.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Why do you mean "null" in called methods?

Comment: Question edited with link (had to push buggy branch). It's hard to put less code to reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Maven plugin is represented by a class that implements the `Mojo` interface (typically `extends AbstractMojo`). It's annotated and such, so that Maven can recognize it, instantiate it (create a new instance) and execute it (call the `execute` method). In your case, this looks something like this:

```
@Mojo(name = "wordcloud")
public class WordCloudMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter
    private String[] includes;

...
```

Maven makes sure that dependencies are satisfied, by injecting these into the new instance of your class, for example the `includes` field above.

If you create any other new and **different** instances of your plugin class, Maven doesn't concern itself with that, and dependencies will **not** be satisfied. In your case, like so:

```
public void execute() {
    final WordCloudMojo wordCloudMojo = new WordCloudMojo();
    Arrays.stream(includes).forEach(inc -> getLog().debug(inc));
    wordCloudMojo.scan(sources);
```

The `stream(includes)` will still use the Maven-injected dependency. But since you call `scan` on a new instance of `WordCloudMojo`, dependencies will **not** be satisfied (the field will likely be `null`).

This would solve that:

```
final WordCloudMojo wordCloudMojo = new WordCloudMojo();
wordCloudMojo.includes = this.includes;
```

Excuse me for not using a mutator method. The `this` is redundant here, but emphasis the problem a bit.

Another solution would be: don't create a new instance of `WordCloudMojo`? What's wrong with the one that Maven already made for you?

Comment: Thanks, so obvious. But I was sticked on.

Comment: Thanks, so obvious, now. But I was sticked on the NPE. ();

I will suppress the new instance.  The base code was not a maven plugin and so there was an instance creation as it was not instantiated elsewhere . So first version was "ok" as I did not need parameters in methods and kept this bad instantiation without issue  . 

Adding parameters, I was missed this part when analyzing the issue.();
Sometimes you so focused on something that you miss obvious cause.